# What is the myme type of a .gem file?

Tags: mime-types, github-actions

so I was setting up an action that would upload to release the build of a gem (so a .gem file), but the action requires asset_content_type for the file to upload. From there the question... what is the mime-type of a .gem file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fairly sure it's `application/octet-stream` which is generally the default for binary content.